# How can I create a select option that I can select from an array in the Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
<div class="row" id="gas_analyte1">
              <div class="col-md-3">
                Gas Analyte 1<br>
                <%= f.select :gas_analyte, @Gases, {include_blank: 'Select Gas', size:15},{style: "width:150px;",class: "gas_search"} %><br>              
              </div>
</div>
```

`@Gases` is an array of gases such as carbon monoxide that is created in the controller.

In Javascript, if a user clicks on the add button, I would like to add another select box to the input page so I have this so far

```
$('#gas_analyte_btn').click(function(){
    $('#gas_analytes').append('<div id="gas_analyte'+(i).toString()+'" class="row"><div class="col-md-3">Gas Analyte '+(i).toString()+'<br><input size="15" type="text" name="search[gas_analyte'+(i).toString()+']" id="search_gas_analyte'+(i).toString()+'" />
});
```

The problem I having is that the javascript created a Textarea and not a select option. How can I create a select option that I can select from `@Gases` in the Javascript?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to use select option you should rather use ``select`` and ``option`` tags

Comment: You could also check out the cocoon gem. It helps with adding fields to a form dynamically.  https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon

Answer (score 1):

I cant understand your question clearly but I think this is what you are looking for .
Giving you an example of which you can safely extrapolate. Cheers.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<select id="sltGas" onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);">
  <option>Hello</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="txtGas" name="txtGas"><input type="button" name="btnAdd" id="addBtn" value="ADD" onclick="addGas();">
<script type="text/javascript">
var sltGas = document.getElementById("sltGas");
alert(sltGas.options[sltGas.selectedIndex].text);

function addGas()
{
 var txtGas = document.getElementById("txtGas");
 var option = document.createElement("option"); 
 option.text = txtGas.value; 
 option.value = 2;
 sltGas.add(option) 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#gas_analyte_btn').click(function(){
  let value = $(this).siblings('input[type="text"]').val();
  if (value.length > 0) {
    $('#myselect').append($('<option>'+value+'</option>'))
                  .val(value); // selects the new value
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="row" id="gas_analyte1">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <select id="myselect">
      <option>Helium</option>
      <option>Hydrogen</option>
      <option>Oxygen</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="add_option">
    <input type="text"/>
    <button id="gas_analyte_btn">Add Option</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also you can programatically create HTML elements and fragments using jQuery or just the vanilla DOM instead of that completely unreadable string concatenation concoction:

```
var id = i.toString();
var $in = $('<input>').attr({ 
  name: 'search[gas_analyte'+i+']',
  id: 'search_gas_analyte'+i
});
# ...
```